# Leaftlet angular overlay image issue

Tags: android, angularjs, ionic-framework, leaflet, native

I have used the leaflet plugin to develop the Ionic hybrid app. When I put it in a native environment, I found that many issues occur. Is there anyway to fix that?

**Issue 1:** the zoom in and zoom out the image will run away randomly.

**Issue 2:** when click the zoom in or zoom out button it will change to full screen.

I have recorded a video to show the problem [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4zIuwATUVr5ZWxuODRLX0V0QW8).

Here is the **code** I have written for the floorplan:

```
var local_icons = {
    defaultIcon: {
    }
  }

    angular.extend($scope, {
    defaults: {
      // scrollWheelZoom: false,
      crs: 'Simple',
      maxZoom: 3
    },
            maxBounds: leafletBoundsHelpers.createBoundsFromArray([[-350, -620], [350, 620]]),
    // maxBounds: leafletBoundsHelpers.createBoundsFromArray([[-540, -960], [540, 960]]),
    layers: {
        baselayers: {
            pwtc: {
                name: 'PWTC',
                type: 'imageOverlay',
                url: 'app/hbe/lib/img/floorplan/hall1.jpg',
                                    bounds:     [[-540, -960], [540, 960]],
                                    // bounds:  [[-540, -960], [540, 960]],
                                    maxZoom: 3,
                                    // minZoom: 1,
                                doubleClickZoom: false,
                                scrollWheelZoom: false,
                layerParams: {
                }
            }
        },
    },
            center: {
        lat: 0,
        lng: 0,
        zoom: 0
    },
});
```

Comment: try this link hope you help it. https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet